# Replacing content in string within NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to replace text within an array and for some reason the code doesn't work, despite no line alert by Xcode, it causes it to crash.

i.e. "name, 2013"

stripping ", 2013"

to result in

"name"

What am I doing wrong, for the life of me I can't work it out and desperately need help on this?

The specific line in question is "case ITSectionTypeAuthor:"

```
- (void)setUpDataByType:(ITSectionType) type andFilter:(NSString *)filter {
    self.type = type;
    self.filter = (filter)? filter : @"";
    [self.sections removeAllObjects];
    NSPredicate *predicate = nil;
    NSString *descriptorKey = @"genus";
    NSArray *rowData = [[ITData sharedObject] animals]; //coming form singleton

    //generate predicate

    switch (self.type) {

        case ITSectionTypeAuthor:
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"describer componentsSeparatedByString:@", "] objectAtIndex:0] LIKE %@", filter];
            break;

        default:
            predicate = nil;
            break;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"describer componentsSeparatedByString:@", "] objectAtIndex:0] LIKE %@", filter];
```

You're creating an objective-c string:

```
@"describer componentsSeparatedByString:@"
```

and then a C-string:

```
"] objectAtIndex:0] LIKE %@"
```

That can't be right, can it?   I think you want:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"describer LIKE %@", [[filter componentsSeparatedByString:@", "] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Comment: The predicate was originally 

`predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"describer LIKE %@", filter];`

and added 

`[[componentsSeparatedByString:@", "] objectAtIndex:0]`

to strip the string of ", "...

Comment: Then I think you want: `predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"describer LIKE %@", [[filter componentsSeparatedByString:@", "] objectAtIndex:0]];`

Comment: Yes that works great! thanks!! Move the last comment to the main answer, thanks again